# Overlapping Div's how to shrink other to fit

Tags: html, css, position

On this little website I'm making I have lots of divs that are set to 100% of the pages width, this allows them to stay centered with the page when you resize it. However for my navigation bar at the top two divs are on the same line as each other so I run into a problem with them overlapping when they get close.

Is there a way to shrink the size of the title div and push it to the top left to make room for the menu?

Fullscreen - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcDKL.jpg
Resized - https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAPEk.jpg

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <title>Premier Choice Holidays</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="designcontainer">
        <div id="bannercontainer">
            <div id="bannerwrapper">
                <img alt="appropriate alt text" class="logo" src=
                "images/logo.png">

                <div id="title">
                    <div class="boldfont">
                        Premier Choice Holidays
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>


                        <li>
                            <a href="findoutmore.html">Find Out More</a>
                        </li>


                        <li>
                            <a href="offers.html">Offers</a>
                        </li>


                        <li>
                            <a href="credits.html">Credits</a>
                        </li>


                        <li>
                            <a href="wireframe.html">Wireframe</a>
                        </li>


                        <li>
                            <a href="admin.html">Admin</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="content">
            <div id="main">
                <div class="smallfont">
                    Your number one destination for holidays
                </div>


                <h2 class="title">Check out some of our exclusive offers
                below!</h2>


                <p class="whitefont">Here at premier choice holidays we offer
                you the best holidays available, from the top right of our site
                you can navigate to our different pages.</p>


                <p class="whitefont">Below you will find some of the popular
                offers we have currentley, you can view more on the "Find Out
                More" page.</p>
            </div>


            <div id="photogrid">
                <h2 class="title">Click an image below to enlarge it</h2>
                <br>


                <div id="photocrop">
                    <a href="offers"><img class="photos" src= "images/property_1.jpg">
                    <a href="offers"><img class="photos" src= "images/property_2.jpg">
                    <a href="offers"><img class="photos" src= "images/property_3.jpg">
                    <a href="offers"><img class="photos" src= "images/property_4.jpg">
                    <a href="offers"><img class="photos" src= "images/property_1.jpg">
                    <a href="offers"><img class="photos" src= "images/property_1.jpg">
                    <a href="offers"><img class="photos" src= "images/property_2.jpg">
                    <a href="offers"><img class="photos" src= "images/property_3.jpg">
                    <a href="offers"><img class="photos" src= "images/property_4.jpg">
                    <a href="offers"><img class="photos" src= "images/property_1.jpg">                   
                    <a href="offers"><img class="photos" src= "images/property_2.jpg">
                    <a href="offers"><img class="photos" src= "images/property_3.jpg">
                    <a href="offers"><img class="photos" src= "images/property_4.jpg">
                    <a href="offers"><img class="photos" src= "images/property_1.jpg">
                    <a href="offers"><img class="photos" src= "images/property_1.jpg">                
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="footer">
            Copyright &copy; Premier Choice 2015
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1100px) {
body {
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#48c0ff;
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat
}

.photos {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    margin:5px
}

#nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0
}

#nav li {
    padding:5px
}

#nav.selected {
    font-weight:700
}
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1100px) {
* {
}

body {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0
}

#designcontainer {
    background-color:#eee;
    font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    background:url(images/banner.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:relative;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    height:auto
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff
}

h1,h2,h3 {
    margin:0
}

#bannercontainer {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto
}

#content {
    padding:0
}

#nav {
    width:600px;
    float:right
}

#nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0
}

#nav.selected {
    font-weight:700
}

#main {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:auto;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.49)
}

#footer {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.42);
    color:#fff;
    text-align:right;
    padding:10px;
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    bottom:-20px
}

#nav li {
    display:inline;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.67);
    padding:10px
}

#title {
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    position:relative;
    top:15px;
    left:200px
}

.logo {
    position:relative;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    left:180px;
    float:left
}

.boldfont {
    font-size:50px
}

.smallfont {
    font-size:18px;
    color:#fff
}

#title2 {
}

.whitefont {
    color:#fff
}

h2 {
    color:#50d7ff
}

#bannerwrapper {
    top:0;
    position:relative;
    color:#fff;
    height:80px;
    width:auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto
}

#photogrid {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:auto;
    width:900px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#6db6ff;
    background:rgba(35,148,247,0.38);
    border-width:1px
}

#photocrop {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    margin:15px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden
}

img {
}

.photos {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    margin:5px
}

.title {
    color:#fff;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center
}

p.blue {
    font-color:blue
}

a:link {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:none
}

a:visited {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:none
}

li:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:underline
}

a:active {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration:none
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put position:static for #nav in media query for smartphones